# How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

What would improve '[Light-weight ladies bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6379)'? I don't understand the answers which it's getting: they're not actionable.

They are theoretical (e.g. "Of course, a smaller bike, with 24" wheels, say, or even 26" would be proportionally lighter", and "I'd go with 26" wheels"), or negative (e.g. "I don't think such a machine exists" and "there are no practical solutions at this point in time"), or not an answer (e.g. "not the lightest").

Am I right in reading that I can't get a light frame, intended for smaller wheels? No light fenders? Not for any price?

They don't stock what I'm asking for at my LBS. If it's not commonly available off the shelf (and I don't see why it isn't) then can it be put together from components? A frame, wheels, drive, maybe flat or raised bars from somewhere? Ought I look for an LBS who can order some or other parts from I don't where and assemble it?

Or is the answer country-specific, e.g. is there a French bike that would suit?

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about this one a bit and looking over your question...

You've got all the necessary details somewhere in your question, but I think you've "[buried the lede](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bury_the_lede)" and maybe rewriting your question with the most important things up front would be better. I think maybe some of the discussion has helped you to refine what you're looking for...

Also you don't say "for any price" in your original question, which makes a huge difference.  If you want to spend $4000-$5000 you could get a custom built bike in titanium or carbon.

> ## Light weight-ladies bike
>
> We bought a bike for a female friend of mine recently. Went for something very similar to the commuter bike I
>   ride, but smaller. After adding on all the accessories we thought
>   she'd need, the bike was too heavy for her to comfortably carry.  Is
>   it possible to find a light-weight ladies bike?
>
> - Rider is 5'4" (160cm) or less. Relatively novice. Expects to wear pants or shorts, not skirts.
> - Bike needs to be light enough for her to carry up and down stairs
> - Needs some way to carry cargo for shopping (rack)
> - flat-resistant tires
> - Probably also needs fenders, bell.
>
> This isn't for racing. It's for riding to and around the local parks,
>   and residential roads. Along roads to the park. For shopping. Along
>   flat bike trails next to waterways. Possibly through town or city
>   traffic.